# Perceived mismatch between hand-rolled re and XPath selector in scrapy shell

Tags: scrapy

I've opened the scrapy shell for the URL I want and am trying to select all instances of p tags such that:

```
<div class="foo"><p>Blah</p></div>
```

But there seems to be a mismatch where I can't get all instances of those tags.

```
In [12]: len(hxs.re("<div class=\"foo"))
Out[12]: 13

In [13]: len(hxs.select('//div[contains(@class, "foo")]'))
Out[13]: 1
```

and in fact, I can't get a full account of p tags with XPath at all...

```
In [14]: len(hxs.select('//p'))
Out[14]: 6
```

What am I missing? I thought line [14] would give all instances of p tags in the document.

Answer (score 0):

The HTML I was trying to select was embedded into a  block, so it wasn't considered valid HTML by XPath. This seems to be a common issue for new scrapy users where the page has ajax/javascript content, detectable by the hashtag in the URI: http://example.com/content1#slide1

All of the content resides in the html code, but your browser needs to run the javascript to populate whatever content the hashtag points to into the DOM itself, which XPath/bs4 look for.

Tt will, however, be pullable with regular expressions, if you're bold (hacky) enough. I'm also considering other alternatives... like making a new XML DOM out of the contents of the script block.